# How to merge filegroups?

Tags: sql-server

Now I have a database with the following files:

PRIMARY FILEGROUP

- 1.ldf

SECONDARY FILEGROUP

- 1.ndf
- 2.ndf
- 3.ndf

I need to merge it into the one primary filegroup with one file. Files from secondary group are not empty.

I can merge files from the same filegroup, but how to do it for the files from a different filegroup?

Answer (score 1):

Move all the objects to the primary file group and then drop the secondary filegroup.

For code see e.g. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5832/move-sql-server-tables-to-different-filegroups/